# Passando valor de uma label para o Arduino via serial

Tags: c#, c, arduino, programação-funcional

Desenvolvi um WindowsForm que contém uma label que faz a verificação de uso de CPU e exibe suas variações, e um botão que conecta o software com o arduino na porta serial disponível. Criei também um textBoxReceber, para verificar se o arduino esta recebendo algum valor, mas ai é que esta o problema, eu não estou conseguindo enviar os valores atualizados para o arduino. Segue o trecho do código.

```
private void startMonitor()
    {
        MachineMonitor machineMonitor = new MachineMonitor("B-NTIDDT001");
        while (true)
        {

            var ram = "Mem RAM: " + machineMonitor.GetUsageMemoryPercentage() + " %";
            var cpu = "CPU: " + machineMonitor.GetUsageCPUPercentage() + " %";

            if (this.lblCpu.InvokeRequired)
            {
                lblCpu.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { this.lblCpu.Text = cpu; });
                this.ValorR = cpu;
            }
            else
            {
                this.lblCpu.Text = cpu;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Aqui está o método que recebe os valores de uso de CPU e RAM e passa para a lblCpu.

```
private void btConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort.IsOpen == false)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort.PortName = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
                serialPort.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
            if (serialPort.IsOpen == true)
            {
                btConectar.Text = "Desconectar";
                comboBox1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort.Close();
                comboBox1.Enabled = true;
                btConectar.Text = "Conectar";
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Minha conexão com as portas seriais disponíveis.

```
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblCpu.Text = RxString;
        RxString = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(trataDadoRecebido));
    }

    private void trataDadoRecebido(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxReceber.AppendText(RxString);
    }
```

Como podem ver, eu não consigo pegar o dados da lblCpu e repassar para meu Arduino. Eu fiz um método lblCpu_Click, dai funcionou porém não quero ter que ficar clicando na lblCpu toda hora, gostaria que atualizasse constantemente sem minha interferência.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você deve usar um timer e fazer um loop de tempo, ou seja você vai escolher um tempo determinado, com por exemplo de 1 em 1 minuto para o método "lblCpu_Click ser acionado.